# Android Change onClickListener in external method when implementing onClickListener

Tags: android, onclick

I'm developing an application where I need to turn off and on the **`onClicKListener`** on some buttons.

I have an external run method where I want to toggle on the `onClickListener` to the buttons. In my onCreate method I have code like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

In a method I call externally (that is a method which isn't onCreate) I have a statement which says `button.setOnClickListener(null);` when a certain condition is fulfilled.

Now I wonder how, to in the same method if another condition is fulfilled turn the `onClickListener` back on. It doesn't work with `button.setOnClickListener(this);`

In my activity I'm implementing `onClickListener` through extends **Activity implements `OnClickListener`** or something.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private boolean enableClick;
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
          {
              public void onClick(View v) 
              {
                  if(enableClick)
                  {
                      // do
                  }
              }
          }
  );

     }
```

You just need to update the value of enableClick.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of setting the onClickListener to null every time you don't want the button to work, why not make use of the enabled property?

```
private Button myButton;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mynewbutton);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(/* your click listener here */);
    myButton.setEnabled(false);
}

private void whateverFunction() {
    if(true) {
        myButton.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        myButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

This way you make it not respond to touches when it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can just implement a `flag` inside the `onClick` method which will guard the methods executing inside `onClick`. No need to set `onClickListener` to `null`, just set `flag` to `false` and the `onClick` method will do nothing. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you just show this through code, how to set the flag? Thanks for the answer

Comment: Yaqub Ahmad posted a piece of code that does exactly that, in his answer